# C++ web Fraemwork

Tags: c++, веб-программирование, framework

Всатала задача написать веб приложение на С++. До этого писал пару приложений на питоне с использование джанго. Остались очень приятные впечатления. Есть ли в мире с++ такой же мощный и приятный в разработке фрэймворк с поддержкой роутинга, шаблонов, орм?... Посоветуйте что-нибудь.

Comment: Если это ещё имеет значение, обратите внимание на:
http://cppcms.com/wikipp/ru/page/main